# Sending mail via Gmail SMTP with PHP Zend error - UGFzc3dvcmQ6

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, zend-mail

I am trying to use the Zend Framework to send mail with Gmail, but have been unable to do so because it seems to reject the username and password (which I can use to login to gmail.com and with Outlook etc).

My PHP code is:

```
<?php

$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp("smtp.gmail.com",array('user' => '****@gmail.com', 'password' => '****', 'auth' => 'login', 'ssl' => 'TLS'));
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($tr);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom('sender@example.com', 'Some Sender');
$mail->addTo('****@hotmail.com', 'Some Recipient'); // my Hotmail account
$mail->setSubject('Test Subject');
$mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.');

try {
    $sent = $mail->send($tr);
} catch (Zend_Mail_Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}

?>
```

The exception thrown by Zend is:

```
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'UGFzc3dvcmQ6
' in C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\lib\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Abstract.php:431
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\lib\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp\Auth\Login.php(95): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(235)
#1 C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\lib\Zend\Mail\Protocol\Smtp.php(217): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp_Auth_Login->auth()
#2 C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\lib\Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
#3 C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\lib\Zend\Mail\Transport\Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#4 C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\lib\Zend\Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#5 C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Wamp\www\Reader\scripts\modules\mail\send.php(63): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#6 {main}
```

By going into Zend\Mail\Protocol\Abstract.php I found that the full $errMsg was:

```
UGFzc3dvcmQ6
5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at                   
5.7.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 fx12sm2756834wbb.59
```

I know that UGFzc3dvcmQ6 is "Password:" encoded in base64, but what does "fx12sm2756834wbb.59" mean, and how can I fix the error - should I be changing the port or ssl or auth or server or something? Or should I try it with another account?

Comment: What happens when you try to send mail using another mail server (ie the one from your internet provider)?

Comment: @Arjan I don't have access to a web host that allows PHP mail() and I will be using this script only on localhost. Unless you mean using sending with something other than gmail? - I have tried connecting to my hotmail account but just got "5.0.0 Authentication Failed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use SSL / OAuth for outgoing mail and Google has [this page](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/) about how to set things up. They also have a page about [problems sending mail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78775) that explains that you need SSL (and that links to another page on how to configure an email client).

I don't know about Zend mail, you probably can configure that to use SSL.

Comment: I get the same error when I change TLS to SSL. Is trying OAuth the best solution? - I'd like to use other mail accounts as well. Also the links under PHP on [google's oauth page](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/code.html) seem to be broken.

Comment: Strange, all sample pages (Java, Python, PHP) and their downloads are working for me. I don't get any broken links there. If TSL and SSL do not work for you, you should try OAuth. Direct link to Google OAuth PHP sample download (zip file): http://google-mail-xoauth-tools.googlecode.com/files/xoauth-php-samples.zip . The link works for me, I get a zip file and can extract it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The pages are working for me now, however I have got what I wanted by using PHPMailer and [Sendmail](http://www.joshstauffer.com/send-test-emails-with-wampserver/) instead of Zend.